# Service Temporarily Unavailable in Magento

Tags: magento

Hi i have this staging website which i develop magento e commerce platform. I encountered an error which i dont know what happened. The error goes something like this

```
Service Temporarily Unavailable

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

I keep on fixing this error but i found out that the error doesnt comes from the files. I tried to add an error php code to test if it executes, But nothing happened. I tried to search on google and it says that

```
Step1: Go to magento root directory.

Step 2: Find the maintenance.flag file and delete it.
```

I already follow this steps. But nothing happened. Can someone help me figured this thing out? Cause ive been stuck on this. Any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: Since this question is not about programming as per the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), it is probably better suited for http://magento.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the file maintenance.flag from your Magento root directory and your website is back. OR It could be a server issue, timeout and so on.

Comment: i just already did the maintenance.flag file in my magento root directory

Answer (score 0):

First, put some test file to the docroot of the magento and see if it works, for example

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

If it works, then check the apache/nginx logs, but i think the problem is with the web server / lb.

Comment: only the checkout page will have this issue. But the rest page it works well